# Find an element following a sequence across rows in a data frame

Tags: r, sequence, rows, apply

I have a data set with the structure shown below.

```
# example data set 

a <- "a"
b <- "b"
d <- "d"

id1 <- c(a,a,a,a,b,b,d,d,a,a,d)
id2 <- c(b,d,d,d,a,a,a,a,b,b,d)
id3 <- c(b,d,d,a,a,a,a,d,b,d,d)

dat <- rbind(id1,id2,id3)
dat <- data.frame(dat)
```

I need to find across each row the **first** sequence with repeated elements "a" and identify the element following the sequence immediately.

```
# desired results

dat$s3 <- c("b","b","d")
dat
```

I was able to break the problem in 3 steps and solve the first one but as my programming skills are quite limited, I would appreciate any advice on how to approach steps 2 and 3. If you have an idea that solves the problem in another way that would be extremely helpful as well.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# Step 1: find the first occurence of "a" in the fist sequence 
dat$s1 <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) match(a,x))

# Step 2: find the last occurence in the first sequence 

# Step 3: find the element following the last occurence in the first sequence
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try reaching a solution with a double `max.col`: In a nutshell, `a1 = max.col(dat == "a", "first")` will give the first appearance of "a" in each row. Replacing the `cbind(rep(seq_along(a1), a1), sequence(a1))` indices of "dat" with "a" and calling `max.col` on `dat != "a"` should return the wanted column indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `filter`:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  x <- as.character(x)
  isa <- (x == "a") #find "a" values

  #find sequences with two TRUE values and the last value FALSE
  ids <- stats::filter(isa, c(1,1,1), sides = 1) == 2L & !isa

  na.omit(x[ids])[1] #subset     
}

apply(dat, 1, fun)
#id1 id2 id3 
#"b" "b" "d"
```

Comment: thanks, works very well, on both the test data and the large-scale data

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is one attempt which is a bit messy,

```
l1 <- lapply(apply(dat, 1, function(i) as.integer(which(i == a))), 
                           function(j) j[cumsum(c(1, diff(j) != 1)) == 1])

ind <- unname(sapply(l1, function(i) tail(i, 1) + 1))

dat$s3 <- diag(as.matrix(dat[ind]))

dat$s3
#[1] "b" "b" "d"
```

or wrap it in a function,

```
fun1 <- function(df){
  l1 <- lapply(apply(df, 1, function(i) as.integer(which(i == a))), 
               function(j) j[cumsum(c(1, diff(j) != 1)) == 1])
  ind <- unname(sapply(l1, function(i) tail(i, 1) + 1))
  return(diag(as.matrix(df[ind])))
}

fun1(dat)
#[1] "b" "b" "d"
```

Comment: thanks this works on the test data set. I will now check this and the previous solution on the actual large-scale data set and hopefully I will be able to solve the problem thanks a lot, i really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming that you have repeated a at each row):

```
library(stringr)
dat$s3 <-apply(dat, 1, function(x) str_match(paste(x, collapse=''),'aa([^a])')[,2])

    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 s3
id1  a  a  a  a  b  b  d  d  a   a   d  b
id2  b  d  d  d  a  a  a  a  b   b   d  b
id3  b  d  d  a  a  a  a  d  b   d   d  d
```

Comment: thanks this works on the test data set. i do not understand all parts of the code but i will now try to apply to the large data and see how it works, thanks a lot, really appreciate the help.

Comment: Or maybe just vectorize the whole thing? `str_match(do.call(paste0, dat), 'aa([^a])')[, 2]`